# How to fetch expired events on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm currently making an event app which displays the past and future events.

I have loaded all the events to the app but I want expired events to be displayed in a separate table.

As a result I was thinking of querying these expired events in the controller however I was wondering if there was a statement to query events that have occurred in the past?

Comment: How do you differentiate between `events` and `expired events`? Is there any column that would separate them?

Comment: I have field called `when` where a user enters the date of the event. I was thinking of querying todays date and comparing it to the `when` field?

Comment: It will be similar like Model.where('when >=?', Time.now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your `when` field is of `date` type, so to fetch the expired events you can do

```
Event.where('when < ?', Date.today)
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I was looking for, if I'm using PG will it make much of a difference for querying the database?

Comment: Cheers and does the format for `when` need to be the same as `Date.today` as I am getting `PG::SyntaxError`?